# Nested configuration arrays in C# CLI

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-interface

I'm busy playing with the configuration methods inside of a C# CLI Application, trying to move some of my hardcoded settings into a more longterm manageable location (config.json).

DeviceTypes[0].ModelCheck[0].Check is returning null, DeviceTypes[0].Vendor and the others are good, and it even appears that the ModelCheck value has the correct array length from config.

The nested array seems to end up not populating with data and I'm not sure why.

Config.cs

```
public class Config
{
    private IConfigurationRoot config;

    private DeviceType[] _deviceTypes;
    public DeviceType[] DeviceTypes { get => _deviceTypes; }

    private Settings _settings;
    public Settings Settings { get => _settings; }

    public Config()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("Config.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        config = builder.Build();

        _deviceTypes = config.GetSection("Devices").Get<DeviceType[]>();
        _settings = config.GetSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
    }
}

public class DeviceType
{
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string ObjectOID { get; set; }
    public ModelCheck[] ModelChecks { get; set; }
}

public class ModelCheck
{
    public string Check;
    public string Regex;
    public string Example;
}

public class Settings
{
    public string[] SubnetPrefix { get; set; }
    public string SnmpCommunity { get; set; }
}
```

Config.json

```
{
  "Settings": {
    "SubnetPrefix": [
      "172.16.0.0/24",
      "172.16.1.0/24"
    ],
    "SnmpCommunity": "Public"
  },
  "Devices": [
    {
      "Vendor": "Extreme Networks",
      "Type": "Switch",
      "ObjectOID": "1.3.6.1.4.1.1916.2",
      "ModelChecks": [
        {
          "Check": "ExtremeXOS version 12.*",
          "Regex": "(?<Model>.*?> version (?<Version>.*?) by",
          "Example": "ExtremeXOS version 12.6.1.3 v1261b3 by release-manager on Thu Jul 21 09:46:07 PDT 2011"
        },
        {
          "Check": "ExtremeXOS.*",
          "Regex": ".*\\((?<Model>.*?)\\) version (?<Version>.*?) by",
          "Example": "ExtremeXOS (X450a-48t) version 15.3.1.4 v1531b4-patch1-3 by release-manager on Sun Mar 17 03:12:24 EDT 2013"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Vendor": "Cisco",
      "Type": "Router",
      "ObjectOID": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.1639",
      "ModelChecks": [
        {
          "Check": "Cisco IOS XR Software.*",
          "Regex": ".*\\((?<Model>.*?>\\),.*Version (?<Version>.*?)[",
          "Example": "Cisco IOS XR Software (Cisco ASR9K Series),  Version 6.2.25[Default]\nCopyright (c) 2017 by Cisco Systems, Inc."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you share json?

Comment: It's available now above, sorry forgot that would have been kinda helpful in assisting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `ModelCheck` is the only class where you did not specify getter and setter access (`{ get; set; }`). I'm guessing here, but could that be the issue?

Comment: Nice catch! Needed fresh eyes, apparently the config binder doesn't like fields, i swapped them to properties and it worked. Getting all the values now.

Comment: Yeah, very simple to spot if you didn't write the code yourself ahah...it's these mistakes that usually take me the longest to catch